# parsing functions from text file without third party

Tags: c#, parsing

I’ve been struggling wrapping my head around parsers and lexers, which I’m not even sure is the best way to tackle my challenge. I don’t want to use any third party libraries because of the unnecessary overhead, project size, and possible license issues. 
Also there won’t be any arithmetic’s, loops, while’s, for’s or foreach’s
It’s a very simple parser that adds or instantiates objects from a text file.
For instance,

```
buildings.addWithMaterials([buildable:mansion], {{[materials: brick], [materials: wood]}, {[materials: wood], [materials: brick]}});
```

Parsing this text would add a Mansion made  of two pieces of brick and wood to the buildings Collection.
The object buildable contains the properties Name which in this case is Mansion
and some building components which in this case are the materials Brick and Wood.
Any tip/direction to search for doing this?
I've looked and searched within stackoverflow, most entries I've stumbled upon refer to third parties
like Sprache and more.

If I missed an article, :/ sorry, please point it out to me

Thanks and kind regards, Nick

Comment: Rethink what you are trying to do. I can already tell this way is going to be full of bugs nightmare.

Comment: How about something like xml or json?

Comment: There's a reason most answers will suggest using an existing parser: it's not nearly as simple as I suspect you think it is. It's also not great to have a custom text file format unless you're really stuck with it. I'd personally suggest using JSON, and then using Json.NET to parse it, unless there's a really compelling reason not to.

Comment: Unfortunatly the source is this format and I have no control over it my preference would go to json or xml aswell

Comment: What's the difference between brick, wood and wood, brick (what do these parameters relate to) What do you have in code so far? Any building / buildable / material classes. Can you post them?

Comment: like the others already pointed out this "unnecessary overhead" is everything but unnecessary. If you know any 3rd party component, that can do it, save yourself the pain of implementing it.

Comment: I have been parsing text for over 40 years and there is nothing I can't get.  Can you post more samples including any header and separators so I can get it right the first time?

Comment: Building house brick and wood is just an example. i Can't post any existing code, due to company policy. Simply said it’s regarding truck configurations engine, suspension, etc. It’s an export from an existing Scala Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing all of the items in your script are in the same format, you can use something like this to parse it:

```
public static class ScriptParser
{
    public static void Parse(string filename)
    {
        string[] script = null;
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
        {
            // read the whole file, remove all line breaks and split 
            // by semicolons to get individual commands
            script = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r", string.Empty.Replace("\n", string.Empty)).Split(';');
        }
        foreach (string command in script)
            HandleCommand(command);
    }
    // as arguments seem to be grouped you can't just split
    // by commas so this will get the arguments recursively
    private static object[] ParseArgs(string argsString)
    {
        int startPos = 0;
        int depth = 0;
        List<object> args = new List<object>();
        Action<int> addArg = pos =>
        {
            string arg = argsString.Substring(startPos, pos - startPos).Trim();
            if (arg.StartsWith("{") && arg.EndsWith("}"))
            {
                arg = arg.Substring(1, arg.Length - 2);
                args.Add(ParseArgs(arg));
            }
            else
            {
                args.Add(arg);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < argsString.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (argsString[i])
            {
                case ',':
                    if (depth == 0)
                    {
                        addArg(i);
                        startPos = i + 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case '{':
                    // increase depth of parsing so that commas
                    // within braces are ignored
                    depth++;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    // decrease depth when exiting braces
                    depth--;
                    break;
            }
        }
        // as there is no final comma
        addArg(argsString.Length);
        return args.ToArray();
    }
    private static void HandleCommand(string commandString)
    {
        Command command = new Command();
        string prefix = commandString.Substring(0, commandString.IndexOf("("));
        command.Collection = prefix.Split('.')[0];
        command.Action = prefix.Split('.')[1];

        string commandArgs = commandString.Substring(commandString.IndexOf("("));
        commandArgs = commandArgs.Substring(1, commandArgs.Length - 2);

        command.Args = ParseArgs(commandArgs);
        command.Execute();
    }
    private class Command
    {
        public string Collection;
        public string Action;
        public object[] Args;
        public void Execute()
        {
            // need to handle any expected commands
            if (Collection == "buildings")
            {
                if (Action == "addWithMaterials")
                {
                    buildings.AddWithMaterials((string)Args[0], (object[])Args[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Eg.
    public static BuildingCollection buildings = new BuildingCollection();
    public class BuildingCollection
    {
        public void AddWithMaterials(string building, object[] materials)
        {
            Building building = new Building();
            foreach (object[] materialsPart in materials)
                // more stuff for you to work out
                // you will need to match the strings to material classes
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ScriptParser.Parse("scriptfile.txt");
```

Note: This lacks error handling, which you will definitely want when parsing a file as it could contain anything.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a direction in how to proceed!